# Excel: importing data from another Excel file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, import

I'd like to use a For loop to import data from 10 other Excel spreadsheets in one go. The names of these 10 other spreadsheets are listed in column A of the sheet "Folders".

I recorded a macro to capture the steps involved in importing data from a file called **TEST FILE**. How can I change this so that each loop uses one of the actual file names, where each file name is stored as the variable **folderName**?

Many thanks in advance.

```
Dim numFolders As Integer
Dim folderPosition As Integer
Dim folderName As String

numFolders = 10

For folderPosition = 1 To numFolders

folderName = Sheets("Folders").Range("A" & folderPosition).Value

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="TEST_FILE", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""C:\Location\TEST FILE.XLS""), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""TEST_FILE1"" = Source{[Name=""TEST_FILE""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#""TEST_FILE1"", [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Name"", type text}, {""Type""" & _
    ", type text}, {""Description"", type text}, {""Format"", type text}, {""Created"", type date}, {""Records"", type text}, {""List?"", type logical}, {""Created by"", type text}, {""Last run"", type date}, {""Last changed"", type date}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=2012_Appeals;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [TEST_FILE]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "_TEST_FILE"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = False

Next
```

Comment: Are all the files in the same folder and are formatted the same? i.e. Are you combining the data from the files into a single table?  If so there's a non-VBA method you could use.

Comment: I'd turn my file list into a table and reference it with a connection only query.  Then use the Get Data > From Folder.  Use Transform Data and merge the folder file list with your required file list based on the file name.  Filter out any nulls and expand the contents.

Comment: The files are all in the same folder, but it's not essential that their data be presented in the one table. Would be interested to hear this non-VBA method!

Answer (score 1):

As an example here's my folder containing the files (don't ask why I'm using xls.... it was just what was in the folder):
[image]

On a worksheet in my workbook I have a table listing the files I'm interested in:
[image]

Create a connection only query to reference the table:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"File List", type text}})
in
    ChangeType
```

Next select *Data > Get Data > From Folder*. This will bring up details of all the files in that folder.
Click *Transform Data*
[image]

Now you want to merge in your file list with the list of files in the folder.
Select *Merge Queries*, identify the *Name* and *File List* columns and click OK.
[image]

Expand the new column by pressing the two arrows at the top of the column and filter out the null values leaving just the files in your table.
[image]

Expand the Content column as you did with the merged file.
Select the sheet or table you're interested in and press OK.
[image]

Your files are now merged and shown in a table:
[image]

Now you can use *Data > Refresh All* to pull any new data from your files, or add new files to the list to import.

Comment: That is the easiest way I will be doing. Importing is best with `ETL` tools like `Power Query`

Answer (score 0):

Reference the file variable folderName and folderLocation where you have 'TEST_FILE' and test_file location hard coded, like below:

```
Dim numFolders As Integer
Dim folderPosition As Integer
Dim folderName As String

numFolders = 10

For folderPosition = 1 To numFolders

folderName = Sheets("Folders").Range("A" & folderPosition).Value
folderLocation = "C:\Location\"+ folderName

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=folderName, Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""" + folderLocation + """), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""TEST_FILE1"" = Source{[Name="""+ folderName + """]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#""TEST_FILE1"", [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Name"", type text}, {""Type""" & _
    ", type text}, {""Description"", type text}, {""Format"", type text}, {""Created"", type date}, {""Records"", type text}, {""List?"", type logical}, {""Created by"", type text}, {""Last run"", type date}, {""Last changed"", type date}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=2012_Appeals;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" + folderName + "]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "_"+ folderName 
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = False

Next
```